# nock: can we have two scopes for two different hosts in nock unit testing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, nock

I'm using nock with  I'd like to know if I can mock api calls from two different hosts defined with their scopes like :

```
const scopeOne = nock('https://myurl1.com/users', allowUnmocked)
.persist();
const scopeTwo = nock('https://myurl2.com/orders', allowUnmocked)
```

API CALLS :

```
scopeOne.post('/users')
.reply(200, (uri, params) =>
({
  users: {
    mtu: 1450
  }
}));

scopeTwo.post('/orders')
.reply(200, (uri, params) =>
({
  orders: {
    mtu: 1420
  }
}));
```

I was able to mock only one url which scopeOne which i defined earlier than scopeTwo. And I also tried seperating scopes in two different files which did not work. Can some one guide me where I was going wrong .

Comment: You can definitely nock two different urls. If you remove the allowUnmocked, do you get an error around the url you're trying to nock?

Comment: Is there any reason or significance of allowUnmocked . As far as I understand , making allowUnmocked = true makes the request on the same hostname to be mocked. So I have two different hostnames with allowUnmocked.

Comment: allowUnmocked lets any request that doesn't match your nock list go through to the original url. If you set it to false, you'll get an error for any request that isn't correctly nocked; which means it will be easier to see if there is a mismatch in your nock params as you'd get an error (no match for request).

Comment: I get this error ->

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Mocks not yet satisfied

Comment: try {
     nockVar.done();
   } catch (e) {
  console.log(`Error! ==> ${e}`); 
}
this is how i m catching error for my nock request .